# Debug Angular 2 Typescript with errors pointing to generated Javascript files

Tags: angular, typescript

When I develop an Angular 2 app in Typescript it compiles to Javascript files. The errors in the browser point to a line number in the .js files e.g.:

`TypeError: Phone.query2 is not a function phone_list.controller.js:5:27)`

However what I want is a pointer to the line in the actual .ts file.

The corresponding sourcemap files are in place and the generated .js files point to the mapfiles e.g.:

`//# sourceMappingURL=phone_list.controller.js.map`

I have tried debugging in Firefox, Chrome and Webstorm.

**Update**

To reproduce follow these steps:

`git clone https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes`

install the npm packages
`npm i`

In dashboard.component.ts add these two lines:

```
var test:any = null;
console.log(test.length);
```

This should cause throwing an error.

Run the project with `npm start`

In the console Chrome shows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js:34:37)
```

Which points to .js files instead of the .ts files

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create map for your code, then for example chrome will download the typescript too and you will see errors and debug in typescript directly. All typescript compilers can do maps

The file will be named xyz.map.js

PS: does your code contain reference to the source map?

Comment: Yes it does but it isn't picked up or something. I have added an example line to the question.

Comment: Did you enabled map files in debugger?

Comment: Yes. I have added the steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the mapping problem was the following. When I ran my project for the first time it had a bug I made in it (as shown in the question). Because of this bug the sourcemaps could not be loaded.

When I remove the bug and load the project again the mappings were made. After this the mapping worked when I introduced the bug again.